# Make JQuery UI Dialog automatically grow or shrink to fit its contents

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a JQuery UI dialog popup that displays a form.  By selecting certain options on the form new options will appear in the form causing it to grow taller.  This can lead to a scenario where the main page has a scrollbar and the JQuery UI dialog has a scrollbar.  This two-scrollbar scenario is unsightly and confusing for the user.

How can I make the JQuery UI dialog grow (and possibly shrink) to always fit its contents without showing a scrollbar?  I would prefer that only a scrollbar on the main page is visible.

Comment: I'd suggest to post a sample of the code, it's difficult to recommend a solution without seeing the structure of the dialog.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

**Update:** As of jQuery UI 1.8, the working solution (as mentioned in the second comment) is to use:

```
width: 'auto'
```

---

Use the autoResize:true option. I'll illustrate:

```
  <div id="whatup">
    <div id="inside">Hi there.</div>
  </div>
   <script>
     $('#whatup').dialog(
      "resize", "auto"
     );
     $('#whatup').dialog();
     setTimeout(function() {
        $('#inside').append("Hello!<br>");
        setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
      }, 1000);
   </script>
```

Here's a working example:
http://jsbin.com/ubowa

Comment: Hmm.. will have to extend my [FrameDialog](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-framedialog) ... it's essentially a method that creates an iframed content for use with dialog.. it isn't perfect, but working well for a project I needed it for.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Instead, I set the option "width" to "auto".

Comment: +1 to the comment -- it worked for me, and the example works as well, so I have to imagine this hasn't changed, but hey, if all else fails, give it a shot.

Comment: This doesn't work for width though, it only works for height I think.

Comment: This answer is no longer valid for version 1.8.4 instead use height auto http://forum.jquery.com/topic/dialog-auto-width

Comment: I get this error: "Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'resize'".

Comment: Error: no such method 'resize' for dialog widget instance

Comment: `{'width':'auto'}` does not work in IE7 and will not be fixed because the `{'width':'auto'}` option is [not supported by jQuery-UI](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4437) according to scott.gonzalez: "Dialog's don't support auto width. The docs state that the option only accepts a number, which will be used for a pixel size. See [jquery-ui-dev thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jquery-ui-dev/6EicX8l7o_4) for a discussion about why we won't support auto width."

Comment: I'm not seeing this work, only because you are adding text that does not span onto the next line. It does not resize with more content.

Answer (score 48):

The answer is to set the

```
autoResize:true
```

property when creating the dialog.  In order for this to work you cannot set any height for the dialog.  So if you set a fixed height in pixels for the dialog in its creator method or via any style the autoResize property will not work.

Comment: Fantastic :) but why jQuery didn't put that at their documentation ?!. Anyway thank u .

Comment: careful, does not work with positioning by trigger plugin (at, my, off etc)

Answer (score 29):

This works with jQuery UI v1.10.3

```
$("selector").dialog({height:'auto', width:'auto'});
```

Comment: Worked for me too (v1.11.1).

Answer (score 13):

I used the following property which works fine for me:

```
$('#selector').dialog({
     minHeight: 'auto'
});
```

Comment: Working in jquery ui 1.12

Answer (score 2):

Height is supported to auto.

Width is not!

To do some sort of auto get the size of the div you are showing and then set the window with.

In the C# code..

```
TheDiv.Style["width"] = "200px";

    private void setWindowSize(int width, int height)
    {
        string widthScript =    "$('.dialogDiv').dialog('option', 'width', "    +   width   +");";
        string heightScript =   "$('.dialogDiv').dialog('option', 'height', "   +   height  + ");";

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(),
            "scriptDOWINDOWSIZE",
            "<script type='text/javascript'>"
            + widthScript
            + heightScript +
            "</script>", false);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var w = $('#dialogText').text().length;

$("#dialog").dialog('option', 'width', (w * 10));
```

did what i needed it to do for resizing the width of the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

If you need it to work in IE7, you can't use the [undocumented, buggy, and unsupported](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4437#comment:9) `{'width':'auto'}` option. Instead, add the following to your `.dialog()`:

```
'open': function(){ $(this).dialog('option', 'width', this.scrollWidth) }
```

Whether `.scrollWidth` includes the right-side padding depends on the browser (Firefox differs from Chrome), so you can either add a subjective "good enough" number of pixels to `.scrollWidth`, or replace it with your own width-calculation function.

You might want to include `width: 0` among your `.dialog()` options, since this method will never decrease the width, only increase it.

Tested to work in IE7, IE8, IE9, IE10, IE11, Firefox 30, Chrome 35, and Opera 22.