# Make JQuery UI Dialog automatically grow HEIGHT to fit its contents (width remains static)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Having looked into [Make JQuery UI Dialog automatically grow or shrink to fit its contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756325/how-can-i-make-a-jquery-ui-dialog-automatically-grow-or-shrink-to-fit-its-conten), I am using the `height: "auto"` option when building a jQuery modal dialog box:

```
$( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: "400",
    height: "auto",
    show: "slide",
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
});
```

However, the height isn't "growing" to fit all of the contents.  I'm still seeing a vertical scrollbar as in this image:

[image: jQuery Modal Dialog Image]

Is there a way right in the definition code I listed to ensure that the height grows enough so that a vertical scrollbar doesn't show?  Or, do I need to do this programmatically before opening the dialog box?

**Edit 1**
Not sure why, but Chrome is displaying this fine but IE 8 isn't.  I need it to specifically work in IE 8 so I believe I'm just going to put a bottom margin on the text.

Answer (score 9):

This all I have done for the dialog box to grow automatically

```
$("#edit_dependent").dialog({

  autoOpen:false,

  modal:true,

  width:800,

  position:["center",20],

  minHeight:"auto"

});
```

Answer (score 2):

That is very strange... I'm not sure how helpful this will be, but I did manage to get the auto-height to work with the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="jqueryUI/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.css" 
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="jqueryUI/js/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: "400",
    height: "auto",
    show: "slide",
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
    });
    $("#dialog").dialog('open');
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="dialog">
1<br />2<br />3<br />4<br />5<br />6<br />7<br />8<br />9<br />10<br />11<br />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It's basically using the same structure you've already established.

Answer (score 1):

This is 4 years Late but i have the same problem.

Wrote code that fixed it

Put a unique class on your dialog:

```
dialogClass:"someClassName"

$(".someClassName").resize(function () {
    var totalHeight = 0;
    var children = $(".someClassName").children(); //get all divs inside the dialog
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if ($(children[i]).innerWidth() > 15) {
            var childrenHeight = children[i].scrollHeight;
            totalHeight += childrenHeight;//make sure your dialog will be the correct height
        }
    }
    $("#idOfContentWithWrongHeight").innerHeight($("#idOfContentWithWrongHeight")[0].scrollHeight);//put the content at the height it should appear
    $(".someClassName").height(totalHeight);//update the height of the dialog
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dJZPV/1/)**

```
 $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
        modal: true,
        height: "auto",
                buttons: {
                    Ok: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                }

            });
            setTimeout(function() {
            $('#inside').append("Hello!<br>");
            setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
  },1000);​
```

Comment: hmmm - so what's special about me?  I just have some regular unformatted text in the div for the dialog.

Comment: Some other css might be effecting with this.Have you checked with that?

Comment: I've taken out all other CSS except for the UI stuff

Comment: Not sure why it's no good for me...I can see your demos working fine but can't figure out why it won't auto resize for me.  All that happens is a vertical scroll bar shows up and grows when I try your "setTimeout" example.  The actual window doesn't grow

Comment: can you provide any link to what you're doing would be helpful.

Comment: Chrome is displaying it correctly, but not IE8 on my PC.  Think I'll just need to put a bottom-margin on the text or something like that...