# Can't make jQuery UI dialog fit it's content when is used with Select2

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am working with a jQuery UI Dialog and a Select2 element inside it. As soon as I click on the INPUT the Select2 does it's job and display a box with search results as the following image shows:

[image]

As you may notice the dialog doesn't grow up and fits the content and I can't find how to fix this. The code I have currently is this one:

```
$('#addSegToUsrDlg').dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    width: 400,
    minHeight: "auto"
});
```

And I should said I have tried also setting `resizable: true` without success. I have read all this topics about the same issue:

- [Make JQuery UI Dialog automatically grow HEIGHT to fit its contents (width remains static)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417915/make-jquery-ui-dialog-automatically-grow-height-to-fit-its-contents-width-remai)
- [Automatically resize jQuery UI dialog to the width of the content loaded by ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231446/automatically-resize-jquery-ui-dialog-to-the-width-of-the-content-loaded-by-ajax)
- [Make JQuery UI Dialog automatically grow or shrink to fit its contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756325/make-jquery-ui-dialog-automatically-grow-or-shrink-to-fit-its-contents)

And apparently them make it work although none talks about Select2. I don't know if the problem is related to the SPAN element that Select2 creates meaning I don't know if a SPAN is capable to make a DIV grow up.

Any advice or solution?

I have created a jsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/u944s4um/) showing the issue

Comment: do you try to set `width` to `"auto"` ?

Comment: @AlexandruMihai yes, doesn't work either

Comment: Can you create a working codepen/JSFiddle of this or provide a URL so that we can see the rest of the code?

Comment: @vic3685 sure, I have added it to the OP ;)